# Problema conexion Base de datos mysql con asp.net core 2.0 en server Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, web, ubuntu, asp.net-core

tengo un problema estoy trabajando en un sitio en asp.net core 2.0, local mente todo trabaja bien la conexión de la BD no da ningún problema, ahora bien el sitio lo subí a Ubuntu 16.04 server, hasta ahí todo bien, ayer subí la bd para hacer la conexión y me encuentro con la sorpresa de este error:

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: connectionString

Cuando voy a entrar a la vista de login me manda este error, estoy totalmente perdida no entiendo que esta pasando, si es algun error de configuración o algo esta mal con mi codigo

Este es mi codigo appsettings.json

```
    {
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {

    "StringDeConexion": "server=localhost;userid=root;password=123;port=3306;database=bd",
    "Context": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Context-f56662ed-1bef-4423-8207-a721623d4659;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

Por otro lado el error se genera es en Starup.cs

```
 public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        // coneccion con MySQL


        services.AddDbContext<Context>(options =>
                options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("StringDeConexion")));

        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        //inicio autenticacion
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {

            options.DefaultSignInScheme = new PathString("/Login/SignIn/");
            options.DefaultSignOutScheme = new PathString("/Login/SignIn/");
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        })
         .AddCookie(options => {

             options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);//tiempo de la sesion
             options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Login/SignIn/");//retorna vista si no hay permisos
         });
        // fin de autenticacion

        services.AddMvc();


    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        // auntentificacion
        app.UseAuthentication();



        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Por favor si me pudiera ayudar

Comment: ¿Por qué hay un `Context` que apunta a *LocalDB* en un   `ConnectionStrings`?

Comment: tengo una clase llamada por ejemplo Context donde tengo mis tablas de la BD, de ahi que hago referencia a esta para poder realizar la conexion

Comment: ¿Hay LocalDB en Ubuntu?

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿estás trabajando en Windows, Mac o en alguna distribución GNU/Linux?

Comment: Okey mi maquina es windows, el servidor donde esta el sitio es Ubuntu apache

Comment: Prueba mandar todo al MySQL local, dejando de lado el LocalDB

Comment: Okey ya logre que mostrar mi pagina de Login quitando localdb, ahora bien sigue sin hacer la conexion a la BD

Comment: revisa la respuesta :)

Answer (score 0):

Observaciones:

Tu cadena de conexión:

```
server=localhost;userid=root;password=123;port=3306;database=bd
```

Debería ser:

```
Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=bd;Uid=root;Pwd=123;
```

Comment: Ya hice el cambio y tampoco conecta

Comment: ¿Aparece algún error?

Comment: No, simplemente no me deja acceder al sitio por que no lee el usuario y contraseña, debo decir que intente agregar la conexion directamente en Startup.cs y me muestra el mismo error de connectioString null

Comment: ¿Tienes acceso a la base de datos en el servidor?

Comment: Si correcto, tengo acceso ya ingrese los usuarios pero no me deja hacer la conexion

Comment: Los usuarios los ingrese manualmente